# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1, Address =0x0)

Tags: xcode, macos

`EXEC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1 , Address 0x0)` This code is in Appledelegate.m after `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.
Occor in a while loop casually and random (if the find events are few no exception occour). Sorry for language and Thank's for any help me ...
Now the source :

```
int trackindex = 14;
MusicSequenceGetIndTrack(sequence,trackindex, &track);

// Iterate throught the select track and add user event
Boolean hasNextEvent = false;
Boolean hasEvent = false;
NewMusicEventIterator(track,&iterator);
MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(iterator, &hasEvent);
MusicEventIteratorHasNextEvent(iterator, &hasNextEvent);

// loop throught track
while (hasNextEvent==true){
    MusicTimeStamp timestamp = 0;
    MusicEventType eventType = 0;
    const void *eventData = NULL;
    int note = 0;
    MusicTimeStamp duration = 0;
    MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(iterator, &timestamp, &eventType, &eventData, NULL);

    if(eventType == kMusicEventType_MIDINoteMessage) {
        MIDINoteMessage *noteMessage = (MIDINoteMessage *)eventData;
        note = noteMessage->note;
        duration = noteMessage->duration;
        UserEvent event;

        event.lenght = 0;
        event.lenght = sizeof(UserEvent);
        event.playedNote = note;
        event.tStamp = timestamp;

        MusicEventUserData *data = (MusicEventUserData *)&event;
        MusicTrackNewUserEvent((MusicTrack)track, timestamp, data);

        counter++;
        printf("counter : %u\n",counter);
    }

    MusicEventIteratorHasNextEvent(iterator, &hasNextEvent);
    MusicEventIteratorNextEvent(iterator);
}
```

Comment: This really isn't enough information to go on. Someone might guess, but unless you're willing to wait for such a flash of random inspiration, you should give us a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (http://sscce.org). If you can't, at least tell us where it crashes, with a stack trace, and (assuming it's inside a MusicSequence function) what the parameters were.

Comment: Besides not being enough of your code, this clearly isn't even _part_ of your code, because `MusicEventUserData`'s `length` member isn't misspelled as `lenght`. (And as a side note, why would you assign 0 and then immediately replace it with `sizeof(UserEvent)`?)

Comment: I'll make one guess before giving up. I notice that you're doing `(MusicTrack)track`. This implies that `track` is of some other type. Unfortunately, you don't show us the definition of the variable or how it gets set. But if you've done something funky like create a struct that includes an `OpaqueMusicTrack` and tried to pass a pointer to that around as a `MusicTrack`, it may end up getting sliced, causing you to read garbage (and then, say, dereference 0 instead of a real pointer), or even (if you get really unlucky) read right off the end of the last page in a block of memory and segfault.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that catches my eye is that "while (hasNextEvent==true)" is not the same as "while (hasNextEvent)".

The second is that, at the end of your loop, it seems odd that you take the "hasNextEvent" of the iterator and then advance it before checking the state. Not sure it's wrong, but it looks wrong.

Comment: Well, it's certainly clearer to call `NextEvent` and then `HasCurrentEvent` instead of calling `HasNextEvent` then `NextEvent`, and it's also what the snippets in the comments in MusicPlayer.h show. But you're allowed to iterate once past the end, so I don't think that's the problem.